# spring cloud feign @Requestparam name containing symbols []

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-feign

i try to create query

```
@FeignClient(name = "geohelper", url = "http://geohelper.info/api/v1")
public interface GeohelperAPI {

@GetMapping(path = "/regions", consumes = "application/json")
GeohelperResponse getRegion(@RequestParam(name = "apiKey") String apiKey, 
                            @RequestParam(name = "locale[lang]") String localeRu,
                            @RequestParam(name = "filter[name]") String region);
}
```

and name of my requestparams contains symbols [ and ].

Created request looks like

`apiKey=somekeysymbols&locale%5Blang%5D=%7Blocale%5Blang%5D%7D&filter%5Bname%5D=%7Bfilter%5Bname%5D%7D`

in values there `{locale[lang]}`  and `{filter[name]}` instead `"rightValueStrings"`

is this a bug? how can I escape this [] ?

Comment: I have the same problem. Could you resolve it?

Comment: no, i don`t resolve it